Using a Node script to create a filter for pandoc
I have a working solution, but it feels fragile. I would like to make it more robust.
I want to use pandoc to convert Markdown files to HTML. I want to use variables such as $title$ and $content$ in my Markdown files, and have pandoc replace these placeholder strings with their values.
This is possible out of the box when using an HTML template file. Your template file will contain all the boilerplate you need, but not the actual content. You can create a YAML block at the top of the template.html file, something like this:
---
title: Page Title
...

Your HTML might include a tag like this:
<title>$title$</title>

When pandoc renders your Markdown as HTML, the output HTML file will contain:
<title>Page Title</title>

However, in the Markdown document which contains the actual content for your HTML page, there are two issues that need to be addressed:

pandoc interprets any $text surrounded by dollar signs$ as Mathematical.
pandoc does not automatically replace any variable names with their values.

My solution for the first issue is to use \$ to escape the dollar signs in my Markdown. Here is a sample.
input.md
---
header: Section Header
content: This is content.
...

# \$header\$

\$content\$

My solution for the second issue is to use a filter. Here is a JavaScript file that I can use to replace a variable like $header$ with the value that is given for it in the YAML block at the top (includes code for debugging):
replace.js
#!/usr/bin/env node

const { createWriteStream } = require('fs')
const logger = new console.Console(createWriteStream("./output.log"));

// Pandoc filter to convert all text to uppercase

var pandoc = require("pandoc-filter");
var Str = pandoc.Str;

function action({ t: type, c: value }, format, meta) {
  log(arguments)
  const keys =  Object.keys(meta).reduce(keyMap, {})

    if (type === "Str"){
    const key = keys[value]
    if (key) {
      const replace = meta[key].c.reduce(replacer, "")
      logKeys(keys, key, replace)
      return Str(replace)
    }
  }
}

function keyMap( map, key ){
  const cue = `$${key}$`
  map[cue] = key
  return map
}

function replacer(result, { t, c }) {
  switch (t) {
    case "Space":
      return result + " "
    case "Emph":
      return result + `<em>${c[0].c}</em>`
    default: 
      return result + c
  }
}

pandoc.stdio(action);

// Useful for debugging

function log(args) {
  const [{t: type, c: content}, format, meta] = args
  logger.log(`type:   "${type}"`)
  if (content) {
    logger.log(`typeof  content: ${typeof content}
        content: ${JSON.stringify(content)}`)
  }
  logger.log(`format: ${format}`)
  logger.log(`meta:   ${JSON.stringify(meta)}`)
  logger.log("")
}

function logKeys(keys, key, replace) {
  logger.log("keys:", keys)
  logger.log(`${key} ==> ${replace}`)
  logger.log("---")
}

This requires installing the pandoc-filter module.
npm install -g pandoc-filter
My code creates a file called output.log so that I can see what is happening in replace.js.
When I run ...
pandoc input.md --filter replace.js -o output.html

... I get the HTML that I expect in the output.html file:
<h1 id="header">Section Header</h1>
<p>This is content.</p>


However, if I change the value of content to This is *content*. (with "content" wrapped in asterisks to indicate italics), output.log shows the value that I would expect...
content ==> This is <em>content</em>.

... but in output.html, the pointy brackets have been replaced by character entities.
<p>This is &lt;em&gt;content&lt;/em&gt;.</p>

Not only that, but my whole replacer() switch{} statement is clunky. It only handles the cases that I have specifically chosen.
How can I make my replacer.js script more generic and robust?

The value sent to the action function is an "abstract syntax tree" (AST), not a string. Instead of returning a string, the action function should return either:

undefined, which means "leave the AST unchanged"
a modified AST

pandoc will then use the modified version of the AST to generate the output.
Here is a corrected version of the action function.
function action({ t: type, c: value }, format, meta) {
  // log(arguments)
  const substitutes =  Object.keys(meta).reduce(keyMap, {})

    if (type === "Str"){
    // value may be a key in substitutes like "$title$"
    return substitutes[value] // undefined if no substitute
  }

  function keyMap( map, key ){
    const cue = `$${key}$`
    map[cue] = meta[key].c
    return map
  }
}


Each time it is called for my input.md, the value of meta is:
{
    "content": {
        "t": "MetaInlines",
        "c": [
            {
                "t": "Str",
                "c": "This"
            },
            {
                "t": "Space"
            },
            {
                "t": "Str",
                "c": "is"
            },
            {
                "t": "Space"
            },
            {
                "t": "Emph",
                "c": [
                    {
                        "t": "Str",
                        "c": "content"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "t": "Str",
                "c": "."
            }
        ]
    },
    "header": {
        "t": "MetaInlines",
        "c": [
            {
                "t": "Str",
                "c": "Section"
            },
            {
                "t": "Space"
            },
            {
                "t": "Str",
                "c": "Header"
            }
        ]
    }
}

The substitutes object maps $content$ to the array at meta.content.c
When action() is called with a value equal to $content$, action() returns this AST array. pandoc then generates the expected HTML using the substituted array.
